# Image quality goes down in php file image upload

Tags: php

I am using a simple image upload php code but the image quality goes down for 100x100 50x50. How can I increase image quality?

I want to a use good quality of photos when they get uploaded.

```
if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

}
else if($extension=="png")
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

 $src= imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);
imagealphablending($src, false);
imagesavealpha($src, true);
imagealphablending($src, false);
imagesavealpha($src, true);
}
else 
{
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
}

echo $scr;

list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);

if($width>75)
{

$newwidth=50;
$newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);


$newwidth1=100;
$newheight1=($height/$width)*$newwidth1;
$tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1,$newheight1);

imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

imagecopyresampled($tmp1,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);


$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$mainfilename = $username.".".$ext;


$filename = "pics/50/". $username.".".$ext;

$filename1 = "pics/100/". $username.".".$ext;

imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,50);

imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100);
```

Can anybody help me to create 4 size thumbnail photos using one large photo but with good quality?

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of `imagejpeg()` is the image quality (not the size as your code seems to imply).

Simply set this to 100 for maximum quality.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Answer (score 0):

From the [imagejpeg documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

```
bool imagejpeg ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality ]] )
```

So to get the highest quality of your image you need to set the quality to 100

```
//0 = lowest, 100 = highest. ~75 = default
imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100);
```